# Rewrite Querystring to File

Tags: .htaccess, query-string

I mirrored our Basecamp install to a Google Cloud Disk using wget.  Many of the pages that were created are using the following file names:

**Files**

```
files.html?page=4
files.html?page=5
files.html?page=6
files.html?page=7
files.html?page=8
files.html?page=9
```

**index**

```
log?n=0
```

---

We were able to fix the index issue with `log%3fn=0`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm log%3fn=0 log report new_more new
```

I wanted to see if there were a way to add a rewrite in .htaccess that will make

**000.000.000.000/projects/11424851-m-domain-com/files.html?page=2**

resolve to the file name that contains a query-string in it.

I am thinking the rewrite would have to produce:

**000.000.000.000/projects/11424851-m-domain-com/files.html%3fnpage=2**

Thank for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}\%3Fnpage=%1? [L]
```

I.e. match query strings starting with `page=`, and redirect to the same filename with the query string appended in escaped form.

Comment: This is the accepted answer with one change:
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}\%3Fpage=%1? [L]`
@outlyer - removed the "n" from %3Fn (my mistake)
Thanks!!